# Error with the %in% operator: numeric vector of a sequence ranging from negative to positive values

Tags: r

I am trying to make a function of the type `y = ax + b` that changes its arguments depending on the values taken by the "x" values. I therefore use the operator `%in%` to detect whether "x" is in the required range of abscissa. There is one of those cases, which is here problematic, where the equation must work for abscissas ranging from negative (-1.02) to positive (0.08) values. I use :

```
as.character(0.07) %in% seq(from = -1.02, to = 0.08, by = 0.01)
FALSE
```

Unexpectedly, this gives me a FALSE result. When I try another x value, with a more restricted range of negative values, it now becomes TRUE :

```
as.character(0.07) %in% seq(from = -0.20, to = 0.08, by = 0.01)
TRUE
```

The same occurs whether I try for negative or positive "x" values. I have absolutely no clue for why this is happening. Worth mentioning I keep with the version "2022.07.2 Build 576" compatible with my windows 8.1 version.

Comment: If you coerce the output from `seq()` to character and look at the results, you'll see where this is going wrong, e.g. `as.character(seq(from = -1.02, to = 0.08, by = 0.01))`.

Comment: I believe this is covered in The R Inferno section of floating point math (edit actually the first paragraph of chapter 1 https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: Also, the very end of the top answer at the duplicate has an explicit solution spelled out for `%in%` in particular.

Comment: As @BillO'Brien points out.  Checkout the result of `as.character(seq(from = -1.02, to = 0.08, by = 0.01))`

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! I actually had no idea of floating points... But this seems to be what happened. I found a tricky solution which could help anybody faces the same problem... :

as.character(0.07) %in% seq(from = -1.02, to = 0.08, by = 0.01)


becomes:

!identical(grep(as.numeric(format(round(0.07,2), nsmall = 2)), as.numeric(format(round(seq(from = -1.02, to = 0.08, by = 0.01), 2), nsmall = 2))), integer(0)) ==TRUE